# Where is the websolr log files stored (when using Heroku)?

Tags: heroku, solr, websolr

I am getting this error message, when reindexing, and I want to inspect the internal server error it reports.

> [2014-12-11 10:37:43 +0000] Start Indexing Error - RSolr::Error::Http
>   - 500 Internal Server Error - retrying... Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error - ignoring... [2014-12-11 10:37:44 +0000]
>   Completed Indexing. Rows indexed 850. Rows/sec: 36.41987405255847
>   (Elapsed: 1.372876796 sec.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websolr support here. Websolr doesn't (yet) provide user-accessible logs. The best bet is to send an email to support@websolr.com and we can get you the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

run something like

```
locate solr.log
```

The log files are normally located in the root of your installation of solr instance inside a folder called logs.

Comment: `heroku run locate solr.log` gives `bash: locate: command not found`

Comment: sudo apt-get install locate

Comment: Or run sudo find / -iname '*solr.log'